# Mysql Query Gives Duplicate Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT 
        tc.expense AS Expense
        ,tc.`tour_sub_code`
        ,tc.login_id
        ,tc.currency
        ,tc.amount
        ,tc.date
        ,tc.from_date
        ,tc.to_date
        ,tc1.NoOfDays
        ,tc1.NoOfDays*tc.amount totalAmount

        FROM tc_wallet tc ,

       (SELECT 
        DATEDIFF(
          STR_TO_DATE(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
          STR_TO_DATE(From_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        ) NoOfDays 
      FROM
        tc_wallet 
      WHERE expense = 'DAILY ALLOWANCE' 
        AND login_id = 'sunny.thangaraj') AS tc1 

        WHERE tc.login_id = 'sunny.thangaraj'
        AND tc.expense = 'DAILY ALLOWANCE'
```

In the above query i am selecting data from same table twice
1) Individual column data
2) DateDiff between columns of same table and using it to calculate total amount

but it is giving me output twice ,

**OUTPUT**

```
DAILY ALLOWANCE TCEB161017  sunny.thangaraj USD 50  12-02-2018  2018-12-08  2018-12-10  2   100
DAILY ALLOWANCE TCEB161017  sunny.thangaraj USD 50  12-02-2018  2018-12-08  2018-12-10  2   100
DAILY ALLOWANCE TCEB010915  sunny.thangaraj USD 2   17-01-2014  2018-12-08  2018-12-10  2   4
DAILY ALLOWANCE TCEB010915  sunny.thangaraj USD 2   17-01-2014  2018-12-08  2018-12-10  2   4
```

Like TOURSUBCODE  TCEB010915,TCEB161017 comes 2 times which is same and is not desired.
Can anyone tell me what wrong am i doing here ?
Is it because i am doing **Select From A,(Select From A)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to remove duplicates is to use a SELECT DISTINCT instead of a SELECT.

However you may better try and improve the query logic. Here I don’t see a good reason to use a subquery, il should be just fine to select just once, as follows ;

```
SELECT 
    tc.expense AS Expense
    ,tc.`tour_sub_code`
    ,tc.login_id
    ,tc.currency
    ,tc.amount
    ,tc.date
    ,tc.from_date
    ,tc.to_date
    ,DATEDIFF(
      STR_TO_DATE(tc,to_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
      STR_TO_DATE(tc.From_date, '%Y-%m-%d') NoOfDays
    ,DATEDIFF(
      STR_TO_DATE(tc.to_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
      STR_TO_DATE(tc.From_date, '%Y-%m-%d')* tc.amount totalAmount

FROM tc_wallet tc

WHERE tc.login_id = 'sunny.thangaraj'
    AND tc.expense = 'DAILY ALLOWANCE'
```

Comment: Hi , @GMB i liked your ans and implemented the same and it worked properly , I had a doubt  i have to again write DATEDIFF(
      STR_TO_DATE(tc.to_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
      STR_TO_DATE(tc.From_date, '%Y-%m-%d') in order to multiply it with tc.amount . Can i use some alias name instead of writing the same DateDiff again

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use an alias in this situation, hence you do have to « DATEDIFF » twice

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        tc.expense AS Expense
        ,tc.`tour_sub_code`
        ,tc.login_id
        ,tc.currency
        ,tc.amount
        ,tc.date
        ,tc.from_date
        ,tc.to_date
        ,tc1.NoOfDays
        ,tc1.NoOfDays*tc.amount totalAmount

        FROM tc_wallet tc ,

       (SELECT 
        DATEDIFF(
          STR_TO_DATE(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
          STR_TO_DATE(From_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        ) NoOfDays 
      FROM
        tc_wallet 
      WHERE expense = 'DAILY ALLOWANCE' 
        AND login_id = 'sunny.thangaraj') AS tc1 

        WHERE tc.login_id = 'sunny.thangaraj'
        AND tc.expense = 'DAILY ALLOWANCE'
```

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx